# How to create a Jetpack app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and recent SDK tools and I'm following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started) to create a sample Jetpack app, but the Create Project wizard in my Android Studio does not have an option called Activity & Fragment + ViewModel and related configuration to create a Jetpack app (Tested on Linux). Any ideas?

Additional info:
Android Studio version: 3.1.2

Comment: In the guide it said android studio version 3.2 or above, use that

Comment: So, it appears 3.2 is not stable yet or it would have prompted me to install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Build your first Jetpack app](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started)

> Launch Android Studio 3.2 or higher, and enter information in the Create Android Project and Target Android Devices as always.

Comment: Despite what the tutorial says in 3.3.1 on Linux the `Activity & Fragment + ViewModel` fragment isn't an option in the creation wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Android Studio 3.3.1 in Linux and also not getting `Activity & Fragment + ViewModel` as an option in the Wizard. However I have a work around.

The `Activity & Fragment + ViewModel` code snippet shows up once you've created a project.

So create your new project with an `Empty Activity`.  Right click inside the file view. Click on: `New -> Activity -> Activity & Fragment + ViewModel`

[image: New -> Activity -> Activity & Fragment]

Then you can continue with the rest of the Jetpack tutorial.